# Weird css with md-badge: square around the number instead of a circle

Tags: html, css, angularjs, gruntjs, badge

I'm using md-badge from angularJs to show the number of notifications a user has. 
But for some reason, css style (from the module) is probably being overwritten. 
From the documentation, when using "md-bage=number"in a tag, you should see a small circle with the #number inside. In my case, I see a huge number with a square around it, I can't understand why.

Here is the html code:

```
<icon
  click-on="vm.clickOnNotifications"
  tooltip=vm.tooltip
  icon="'notifications'"
  md-badge={{vm.notificationsCounter}}
  md-badge-fill="white"
  md-badge-color=":red"
>
</icon>
```

Here is the html code generated when i inspect the page:

```
<div class="md-badge" style="position: absolute; color: rgb(244, 67, 54); background-color: white; display: initial; left: 397px; top: 29px;">3</div>
```

Here is the official documentation and what it should look like: 
https://jmouriz.github.io/angular-material-badge/demo/demo.html

And here is what I'm seeing: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpkC5.jpg

Any idea? What extra info should I send here?
Thanks!

Here is my gruntfile code (part of it):

```
injector: {
      options: {
        ignorePath: 'static/'
      },
      dev: {
        files: {
          'static/index.html': [
            'static/app/app.js',
            'static/app/app.config.js',
            'static/app/**/*Module.js',
            'static/app/**/*Route.js',
            'static/app/**/*Ctrl.js',
            'static/app/**/*Service.js',
            'static/app/**/*Directive.js'
          ]
        }
      },
      production: {
        files: {
          'static/index.html': [
            'static/app/assets/css/**/*.css',
            'static/app/assets/js/*.js'
          ]

        }
      }
    },
```

(obs: this made it work)
I have copied angular-material-badge/angular-material-badge.css file to a folder in assets/css/ so grunt file can put it in my index file. When i run grunt dev, I have my index like:

```
<!-- injector:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/angular-loading-bar/loading-bar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/angular-material-badge/angular-material-badge.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/angular-material-data-table/md-data-table.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/angular-material-icons/angular-material-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/angular-material/angular-material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/assets/css/style.css">
```

<strike>Still weird css in the badge.</strike>
Solved, thanks John =)

Comment: Obviously, your badge is affected by some CSS you're not sharing. Unless you create a [mcve] where we could inspect the issue, we have zero chances of finding the cause.